# Joomla trigger function when clicking delete (trash)

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm creating a custom component for Joomla 3.0 but need to know how to run a function when the user clicks "empty trash" in the administrator side.

The function I'm trying to run would delete an image from the filesystem. JToolBarHelper::deleteList seems to only take a javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Its take you to the JS function  like

```
Joomla.submitbutton('banners.trash');
```

But this case it will call the trash function in the joomla's

```
libraries\joomla\application\component\controlleradmin.php
```

here you can register new task. if you need but i don't suggest to add/edit core joomla files.

You can achieve this in another way.

like

```
Joomla.submitbutton('banners.Custom_trash');
```

or any other name or (same).
Write the function in your components/controller.php (that specific submission related controller).
Then you will get control inside your controller.
In this way you can override the joomla's default functions in your component.

Hope this will help you ...

Comment: Absolutely awesome - many thanks Jobin, extremely helpful! The Joomla.submitbutton for emptying the trash is "mycomponent.mydelete" - so I copied the delete function from libraries/`legacy`/controller/admin.php and renamed it mydelete.  This works great but how would I get any other stored value for the item?  I can get the item's ID by using JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('cid', array(), 'array') but am stuck with the logic for how to get the item's other 'fields'?